# Insert Control into ASP.NET Menu Control?

Tags: asp.net, xml, authentication, controls, sitemap

I have a site that uses a menu control tied to a sitemapdatasource which calls from a xml sitemap file. I want to add to this menu a Login/Logout control. Is this possible?
Dave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking if you can somehow define the login control in the xml of the sitemap file - I don't think this is possible.

You could programatically add a new menu item to the menu after the menu control has been databound though.